# Use FlatDir in Gradle DependencyResolutionManagement

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I wanted to use a local dependency (a jar file) relative to my root project directory in my main module as a buildscript classpath via `dependencyResolutionManagement` in `settings.gradle.kts`.

Here's my `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
      
        flatDir { dirs = setOf(File("plugins")) }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "AndroidApp"
include(":main", ":base")
```

However, gradle is resolving the path as `C:\Users\Name\.gradle\daemon\7.5\plugins`

I have tried below and none of them works:

```
1. File(".").absolutePath // C:\Users\Name\.gradle\daemon\7.5\.
2. rootProject.path // :
3. rootProject.children.size // 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. I have made two mistakes:

1. I need to declare in the pluginManagement block instead.
2. Although it's resolving to gradle path initially, but it will use the correct relative path while resolving in the main module.